# How to join multiple tables in MySQL 3?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I want to see a citizen's full name with their emails

where notifyEmployee ='1' in reportBasket,reportNoBasket tables

AND count email from reportBasket, citizenEmail reportNOBasket in one counter

Tables:

> citizen(email, firstname,lastname)
>
> reportBasket(email,notifyEmployee)
>
> reportNoBasket(citizenEmail, notifyEmployee , groupEmail)

**Before** I was use this query

```
SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname), count(*) as citizen_count 
FROM (
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname
FROM reportBasket rb
JOIN citizen c
    ON rb.email = c.email
WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname
FROM reportNoBasket rnb
JOIN citizen c
    ON rnb.citizenEmail = c.email
WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
) as T
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
ORDER BY firstname, lastname ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS fullname, count(*) as email_count     , email AS email
FROM (
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname,c.email
FROM reportBasket rb
JOIN citizen c
    ON rb.email = c.email
WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email
FROM reportNoBasket rnb
JOIN citizen c
    ON rnb.citizenEmail = c.email
WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
) as T
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
ORDER BY firstname, lastname ASC ;
```